# Find the eigenspaces corresponding respectively to each eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $u$ and $v$ be $2$ non-zero (column) vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $A = I- uv^T$ where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

a) Prove that $A$ has $2$ eigenvalues $λ_1 = 1$ and $λ_2 = 1-v^Tu$.
Which property should the vectors $u$ and $v$ satisfy
in order for $A$ to be singular?

b) Find the eigenspaces (the set of eigenvectors) $E_1$ and $E_2$ corresponding respectively to $λ_1 = 1$ and $λ_2 = 1 - v^Tu$.

My attempt:

a) Consider the matrix $B=uv^T$ first. When $n\ge2$, since the rank of $B$ is at most one, $B$ always has a zero eigenvalue and it has at most one nonzero eigenvalue. If $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ corresponding to a nonzero eigenvalue $\gamma$, then $(v^Tx)u=uv^Tx=\gamma x$. Therefore $u$ is necessarily a scalar multiple of $x$, meaning that we can take $x=u$. Conversely, $u$ is indeed an eigenvector of $B$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\gamma=v^Tu$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $B$ are $0$ and $v^Tu$. In turn, the eigenvalues of $I-uv^T=I-B$ are $1$ and $1-v^Tu$.

for $A$ to be singular, its $\det = 0$,so $\det(I- uv^T)=0$, but $\det(I- uv^T)= 1 - v^Tu$, hence $1-v^Tu = 0$, which implies that $v^Tu = 1$

b) I know I should solve $(I - uv^T)x=\lambda x$. But how to solve this for my two $\lambda$'s. Any help please? Thank you

Comment: You essentially solved this already in a). Just note that $I-uv^T$ and $uv^T$ have the same eigenspaces.

Comment: could you be more explicit please?

Comment: You already showed in a) that the eigenspace of $uv^T$ corresponding to $v^Tu$ is the linear span of $u$.

Comment: yeah, but this is for $v^Tu$ only. but what about $\lambda_2 = 1 - v^Tu$ and $\lambda_1 = 1$?

Comment: The equation $(I-uv^T)x = (1-v^Tu)x$ is equivalent to $(uv^T)x = (v^Tu)x$. That's what I meant by $I-uv^T$ and $uv^T$ have the same eigenspaces.

Comment: Oh Okay I see now! Thanks. And for $\lambda_1 = 1$, we have $(I-uv^T)x=x$, so what are my eigenvectors here?

Comment: Again, this is equivalent to $(uv^T)x = 0$. I'll leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: so $x = 0$ in that case?

Comment: Just do as you did above: $(uv^T)x = (v^Tx)u = 0$. Hence...?

Comment: so the eigenspace of $uv^T$ corresponding to 1 is the linear span of $u$ as well?

Comment: No, that's obviously impossible. It's all vectors $x$ that satisfy $v^Tx = 0$, i.e. those that are orthogonal to $v$.